# How to get ids from grouped image inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, input

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/95h4od4w/3/) shows two rows of inputs of type image. When one of the inputs is clicked on, it is marked as `selected`. I can't figure out two things :

1. How do I find the last selected input. That is, if you click on yellow and then on red, I need to know that yellow was the previously selected item. I added a line to display the id but it's not working.
2. I need to know which group the input that is selected is in  `group_one` or `group_two`.

Can anyone help with this?

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div><img src="outside.img"></div> 

    <div id="group_one">
     <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red"><input id="enlarge" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="red" type="image" src="red.gif"></div>
     <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow"><input id="enlarge" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="yellow" type="image" src="yellow.gif"></div>
     <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white"><input id="enlarge" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="white" type="image" src="white.gif"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="group_two">
     <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red"><input id="enlarge" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="red" type="image" src="red.gif"></div>
     <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow"><input id="enlarge" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="yellow" type="image" src="yellow.gif"></div>
     <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white"><input id="enlarge" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="white" type="image" src="white.gif"></div>
    <div id="showid"></div>

    <script> 
      $("input").click(function(){

      var id = $(this).parent().parent().find(".selected").attr('id');  
      $("#showid").text('id= '+id);

      $(this).parent().parent().find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
     });
    </script>      

    <style>
    .imgStr {display:inline-block }
    .selected{ box-shadow:0px 12px 22px 1px #333;}
    div.shadow { border: 0px solid #3DA1D2; padding: 10px; }
    div.shadow:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
    }            
    </style>
```

Comment: `id`s within a document are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to give the containers the same class (`container` in my example) then select them simply using `closest('.container')` :

```
$("input").click(function(){
  var current_selected = $(this).closest('.container').find(".selected");
  $("#showid").text('id= '+current_selected.attr('id'));

  $(this).closest('.container').find(".selected").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass("selected");  
});
```

**NOTE :** The `id` should be unique in the same document.

Hope this helps.

```js
var last_selected;

$("input").click(function(){
  var current_selected = $(this).closest('.container').find(".selected");
  $("#showid").text('previous selected = '+current_selected.attr('id'));

  $(this).closest('.container').find(".selected").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass("selected");  
});
```

```css
.imgStr {display:inline-block }
.selected{ box-shadow:0px 12px 22px 1px #333;}
div.shadow { border: 0px solid #3DA1D2; padding: 10px; }
div.shadow:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img src="outside.img"></div> 

<div class='container' id="group_one">
  <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red">
    <input id="red_1" class="imgInput selected" name="img_front_group" value="red" type="image" src="red.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow">
    <input id="yellow_1" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="yellow" type="image" src="yellow.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white">
    <input id="white_1" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="white" type="image" src="white.gif">
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container' id="group_two">
  <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red">
    <input id="red_2" class="imgInput selected" name="img_front_group" value="red" type="image" src="red.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow">
    <input id="yellow_2" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="yellow" type="image" src="yellow.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white">
    <input id="white_2" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="white" type="image" src="white.gif">
  </div>
  <div id="showid"></div>
```